# Grid system html

Tags: html, css, grid

[image]

I was just wondering if someone can give me a hand, i've tried for 3 hours to solve this issue. I need to have the interface like on the picture by using grids, or anything.
The closest thing i can get is when everything displayed correctly except the second bottom grid. It usually gets below the white line (thats the starting point). 
Could someone give me a tip on how to get around this problem.

Comment: The main question is how to control the height by using grids? the width is not a problem to use, its easy, but when it comes to different height, my grid  seems to be losing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have minimum two options:

one is to make the grid elements absolutely positioned and give them top, left, right and bottom values. The parent element (grid container) should have "position:relative;" (or can be fixed or absolute, but in your case relative will make more sense).

Another option is to write markup like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
 one
</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
 two
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
three
</div>
```

Basically you wrap the two divs on the left into one parent div so the layout will not break. Just make sure the height of inner divs are 50% of the height of the right box.

Comment: it worked, i dont use bootstrap so took a while to change around, hgihly appreciate it.